# Regarding deletion of one to one relation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a question regarding the one to one relationship
I have a model

```
Car 
 has_one:company
```

and

```
Company:
  belongs_to:car
```

so as a result I have car_id column in Company model. So when a create a new car for a particular company and pass the parameters the car_id value automatically gets updated to the new car_id created.
However when I destroy or delete a particular car the corresponding company's car_id doesnot get updated to nil.It remains as it is which is undesirable because there is no such car_id exists.I want to change the car_id field of the corresponding company to nil when I delete particular car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Car
    has_one :company, :dependent => :nullify
end
```

This should set the car_id to null in company table. But, I wonder if this association should be has_one_through instead of has_one.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Car 
    has_one:company, :dependent => :nullify
```

this will do it